# Inheritance in C# multiple properties for a single property

Tags: c#, inheritance

How would you inherit from one class and have multiples of a single property from it Example

And here is the actual code (So Far)

```
class NetWorkInterface
{
    public double Vlan;
    public string Ip;
}

class Port : NetWorkInterface
{
    public double PortNumber;
}
public void test ()
{
    Port newport = new Port();
    newport.PortNumber = 7;
    newport.Vlan = 100
}
```

I want to be able to add multiple interfaces to one port

Comment: let me get rid of that one

Comment: maybe I need to just add a list of networkinterfaces to the port rather than trying to inherit

Comment: Yes, that is called composition, inheritance is not the right fit here, if a port can have multiple interfaces, its a has-a (composition) relationship, not an is-a (inheritance).

Comment: You need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should be using inheritance here.

If you want a `Port` to contain a collection of `NetworkInterfaces` then a better definition of `Port` might be:

```
class Port
{
    public double PortNumber;
    public NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces;
}
```

Comment: yea I am thinking the same thing now, just saw a video on it now inheritance is stuck in my head, trying to hard to use it

Comment: You need to remove the inheritance from your code sample, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would use it if I needed to say, create a backhaul Port, which is a port but has some extra details, so it would inherit from the base class port.

Comment: I would change the name `Port` to something like `NetworkPortBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines off

```
    public class Port
    {
        public double PortNumber { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<NetworkInterface> NetworkInterfaceList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You add almost nothing to the existing answer by @Slappywag

Comment: Great minds I suppose. there was no answer as I composed my masterpiece.

Using arrays is pretty oldskool though. Also public fields are less good than properties (encapsulation baby!) so I win.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit one class per class (no multiple inheritance in C#), or implement multiple interfaces, or do both

```
public interface NetWorkInterface1
{
  double Vlan {get; set;} 
}

public interface NetWorkInterface2
{
   string Ip {get; set;}
}

class Port : A /* (inherit class before interface) port inherits A & A inherits B*/, NetWorkInterface1, NetWorkInterface2 /* implements interface 1 & 2*/
{
    public double PortNumber;
    public double Vlan {get; set;} 
    public string Ip {get; set;}
}

public class A : B /* A inherits B */
{
  public string AStuff; 
}   

public  class B
{
  public string BStuff;         
}


public void test ()
{
    Port newport = new Port();
    newport.PortNumber = 7;
    newport.Vlan = 100;
    newport.AStuff = "A"; 
    newport.BStuff = "B"; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, he isn't trying to implement multiple interfaces. He's attempting to implement a single interface multiple times.